# The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, reportviewer

Rendering report shows a blank page and on view source mode it shows the following Error "The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application" even after doing the web.config changes.

Comment: So, what's your web.config now?

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers> <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />